# get nearest lat long around 25 km from given array lat long

Tags: php, google-maps, dictionary

i have `array` of lat long like :

```
var locationList = new Array( '23.2531803, 72.4774396', '22.808782, 70.823863', '24.3310019, 72.8516531', '22.3073095, 73.1810976', '22.3038945, 70.8021599', '23.850809, 72.114838' );
```

i want get nearest around 25 km 's lat long from first given array which is `23.2531803, 72.4774396`

are there any calculation for nearest 25 km 's lat long from given array.

```
NOTE: for some reason i can not use sql query, because i get lat long from given address
```

Comment: locationList is a javascript-array, any reason why the question is tagged as PHP?

Comment: i am using php, and i have array of address in php, so i am converting in to java script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Calculate the distance between your start coordinate and every subcoordinate
Step 2: Pick the smallest distance
Step 3: Is it < 25 km? Success!

How to calculate distance between two coordinates:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

$D = 6371; // Earth Radius
$dLat = $lat2-$lat1;
$dLon = $lon2-$lon1;

$a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) +
     sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2) * cos($lat1) * cos($lat2); 

$b = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a)); 
$c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a)); 


return $D * $c;

}
```

This function thinks of the Earth as a perfect ball, which it is not - slight variations do apply, but are neglible at the 25km diameter you want.

Comment: what will be valu of `$lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2` ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to do a first "rough" sort to weed out all data points that are outside a square with the source in the center. Otherwise you might use a lot of computational power to find out that some point is 500 km away from your starting point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your data array is awfull. You need to make your data more computer readable. Then you can use [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to calculate the distance from each location. You can save the first distance and index in an variable then replace it with new distance and index if it's shorter.

```
var closest = {id:0,dist:-1};
var myloc = [23.2531303, 72.4774398]
for(var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++)
{
  var long_lat = locationList[i].match(/([0-9.]+)+/)
  long_lat[0] = parseFloat(long_lat[0]);
  long_lat[1] = parseFloat(long_lat[1]);
  var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(long_lat[0] - myloc[0], 2)+Math.pow(long_lat[1] - myloc[1], 2)));
  if((closest.dist == -1) || (closest.dist > dist))
  {
    closest.dist = dist;
    closest.id = i;
  }

}
```

Comment: +1, but be aware that Pythagorean theorem is quite imprecise because Earth is spherical, not flat :) Think about it, for example, the more you are near to the north and south poles, the coordinates vary quicker in little distances.

Answer (score 0):

When you like to calculate in JS you may use [google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#spherical) to calculate the distance between the single points.

Store the results in an array, sort the array and when the smallest entry is <25km you got what you want.